# How does lubridate (R) compute the number of months between two dates?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to translate some feature engineering routines from R to Python and stumbled accross this code line within the R codebase:

```
interval(ymd(VERSTARTDATUM),ymd(SERMELDEDATUM)) %/% months(1)
```

After some reading I figured that R seems to consider a month to consist of 30.4375 days on average and that R uses that constant to compute the number of months between two random dates. In a nutshell, R computes how many 30.4375 days two dates lie apart. So I came up with this Python (Pandas) code as translation:

```
(df['VERSTARTDATUM'] - df['SERMELDEDATUM']).abs().dt.days.div(30.4375).round().astype(int)
```

The resulting data match in 97.95034% of all obversations (4970 out of 5047).
Upon investigating why it does not always match, I figured that R behaves in a way I seem unable to grasp! The following code:

```
print(interval(ymd('2017-02-03'),ymd('2018-03-05')) %/% months(1))
print('--------')
print(interval(ymd('2017-02-03'),ymd('2018-03-05')) %>% as.numeric)
print(months(1) %>% as.numeric)
print('--------')
print(34128000 %/% 2629800)
print('--------')
print(34128000 / (days() %>% as.numeric * 30.4375))
```

outputs this:

```
[1] 13
[1] "--------"
[1] 34128000
[1] 2629800
[1] "--------"
[1] 12
[1] "--------"
[1] 12.97741
```

So R seems to round the 12.97741 months (with a month consisting of 30.4375 days) up to 13 months, which can be considered reasonable I suppose.

But now, the following almost identical code (the only difference being that the two dates are swapped with different dates):

```
print(interval(ymd('2015-06-19'),ymd('2017-07-18')) %/% months(1))
print('--------')
print(interval(ymd('2015-06-19'),ymd('2017-07-18')) %>% as.numeric)
print(months(1) %>% as.numeric)
print('--------')
print(65664000 %/% 2629800)
print('--------')
print(65664000 / (days() %>% as.numeric * 30.4375))
```

prints the following:

```
[1] 24
[1] "--------"
[1] 65664000
[1] 2629800
[1] "--------"
[1] 24
[1] "--------"
[1] 24.9692
```

Now it seams that R rounds 24.9692 months (with a month again consisting of 30.4375 days) down to 24 monthes (which my Python equivalent of course does not - hence the discrepancy within 104 of the 5074 obvervations).

My question is simple: How does R compute the number of months between two days. Apparently not the way I though it would.

Comment: Where is this code from? `months(1)` appears to use a custom `months` function.

Comment: Hi Hugh
Its from the "lubridate" package.

Comment: *"After some reading I figured that R seems to consider a month to consist of 30.4375 days on average and that R uses that constant to compute the number of months between two random dates"* <- do you have a reference for that

Comment: You are using a package, where design choices were made by the package authors. This isn't about R's design choices at all. FWIW, base R provides the `difftime` function, which does not allow output for units above weeks, precicely because it isn't a universally defined problem.

Comment: Mark:
One of many sources: https://sscc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/dwr/dates.html
Also, try: (months(1) %>% as.numeric) / (days() %>% as.numeric)
It again results in 30.4375

Comment: @Silverdust the thing you linked to talked about lubridate, which is a package of R, but not really R per se. I can see how you would get them confused, but to attribute to R what one package has chosen to do is where your problem is

Comment: I adapted the title and added lubridate as tag.

Comment: `mean(c(31, 28.25, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31))` gives 30.4375 (days). It seems sensible to define a month as that, i.e. 2629800 seconds.

Comment: @Roland
Exactly. But then why the rounding errors? ;-) Why is he rounding 12.97741 up to 13 and in another case 24.9692 down to 24?

Comment: lubridate internally calculated  24.96667 but return 24, as its 24 complete months; this is not R's choice, it is the package writer of Lubridates choice. The code for the lubridate implementation, specifically division is available here https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/main/R/ops-division.r

Comment: if after you load lubridate you set `debug(lubridate:::divide_interval_by_period)` then you will be dropped into R Browser() when the division is performed, and can step through the calculation to monitor it as it goes

Comment: @Nir Graham
I get that, but why is lubridate then not considering 12.97741 as being 12 complete months, but 13 all of the sudden? ;-) I'll try the debug thing :-)

Comment: `ymd('2017-02-03') + months(13)` returns "2018-03-03", which means your interval is slightly longer than 13 months. The division of objects of classes "Interval" and "Period" is defined in such a way that it is consistent with addition and subtraction. You should read `help("Period-class")`.

Comment: lubridate, is not evaluating 12.97741, rather est+frac= 13.00469 which rounds to 13

Comment: @Nir Graham
So I used the debugger and kind of tried to understand the code in the repo of lubridate. I figured that the initial estimate divide_interval_by_period comes up with 12.97741. But after calling the adjust_estimate helper function, the final result is 13.00469, which is then rounded down to 13, which is the final result. But I cannot really wrap my head around what adjust_estimate really does, or how, or why?

Comment: There is some textual description here, perhaps it helps : https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/mplus.html